# Hora FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema al momento de pasar mis datos en HTML

Tengo esta línea de código en javascrtipt

```
 eventClick: function (info, jsEvent, view){
    $('#CalendarioModal').modal();
    console.log(info);

    $('#idC').val(info.id);
    $('#titleC').val(info.title);
    $('#colegioC').val(info.colegioC);
    $('#horaS').val(moment(info.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY / HH:mm'));
    $('#horaF').val(moment(info.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY / HH:mm'));
    $('#description').val(info.description);
});
```

con respecto a HTML, tengo estas líneas.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Fecha Inicio:</h2>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="inicio" value="" required>
                        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fyhIC" id="fyhIC" readonly> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Fecha Fin:</h2>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="fin"  value="" required>
                        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fyhFC" id="fyhFC" readonly> -->
                    </div>
```

y al momento de mostrar los datos en mi modal no me sale la fecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: El formato no es el correcto para el campo input datetime. Saca lo de moment y de deja `$("#horasS").var(info.start)`

Comment: Gracias, se solucionó!